# Laravel Vue.js - Exact Same Code doesn't render in a different environment

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I have developed a Vue.js client on an empty Laravel app. When I moved the client to my production system it shows it running without any errors but doesn't render anything. Below is the setup summary:

1. Both deployments are on Laravel 5.6 - Production migrated from 5.1
2. The production system has other Laravel routes in the same route file and cannot be moved elsewhere.
3. `package.json` files are identical.
4. SASS files are identical and so are the Vue.js files.
5. The big difference between the two is the route in `routes/web.php` for Laravel.

For Non Production the route is as below and `welcome.blade.php` is the only view:

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```

For Production the route is below and we are pointing to `app.blade.php` instead of `welcome.blade.php` as `welcome.blade.php` is being used for a default landing page. Basically it is in a sub-directory.

```
Route::get('mywebapp/{path}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```

Update:  It seems like it has something to do with the history mode.  My current settings are:
mode: 'history',
fallback: true, 
linkExactActiveClass: "active",

However, if I disable the history mode i.e. set it as mode:'' the views start rendering.  This creates another issue for me.  I am using vue-authenticate for social login (e.g. Google, Facebook, Microsoft Live) and each one of them requires me to provide a callback.  I don't think that I can put a # in the callback url that I have to enter when creating the keys.

Is there a way I can handle the history mode in the .htaccess or laravel route file.

Comment: Have you moved this from a local server to a live server? Have you installed npm?

Comment: How are you loading the js file? Can you show the line that loads the js in your blade template?

Comment: @ColinBarstow - No i have two different domains configured as virtual hosts on the same Ec2 instance.  I have copied files from on to the other over. yes, I have NPM installed on bot and node_modules were resinstalled when moved to prod and another build was done.

Comment: @devk   -  I have tried both <script src="/js/app.js"></script>  as well as <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script> .  Latter one works in the dev environment fine.

Comment: is there an actual `mywebapp` dir on the server that is within the defined HTTP server Document Root? Or is the document root set to your Laravel app `public` dir and the `mywebapp/` is just part of the route definition?

Comment: no it is defined via the route.  Please see the code above. I am using the laravel vue.js preset so that I dont' have to build /install a vue app in a public folder.

Comment: Is the `js/app.js` loading succesfuly? Are there any console errors in production?

Comment: Yes it is loaded successfully.

Comment: Please see additional updates I have made to the original post.